# How can I change the animation timeline frame rate on Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

The animation timeline on Photoshop CS5 seems to be locked at 30fps is there a way of increasing this frame rate?

[image: Snippet of Photoshop CS5 Animation Timeline]

I have tried increasing the fps when exporting the animation through 'Render Video'.

[image: Snippet of Photoshop CS5 Render Video window]

This lets me choose a custom frame rate, however when it is increased to 60fps this only adds duplicate frames to make up the missing 30fps resulting in a very noticeably choppy animation when played at 60fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeline settings can be edited through the Document Settings.

1. From the Animation Timeline menu select **Document Settings** to enable the Timeline settings.
2. Set frame rate to 60 fps.

[image: Click on the expand Animation Timeline Menu]
[image: Select Document Settings]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Well, now it's different..

you will see entry called `Set Timeline Frame Rate` in this burger menu

[image]

and then type your desired `fps` or select one from the drop down menu

[image]